# Hide jquery tool-tip after sometime, even if the mouse is still over the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want that the tooltip should hide automatically after few seconds.Even if the mouse is over the element, still the tooltip must hide after sometime.
I am using the jquery tooltip pluggin.

Comment: Please add some code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Add `setTimeout` to `open` event:

```
$( '#field' ).tooltip(
  open: function( event, ui ) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      $( '#field' ).tooltip( "close" );
    }, 3000);
  })
;
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/112g/ybgzw7o6/)